# Pandas drop_duplicates only possible after to_csv and read_csv

Tags: python, pandas, drop-duplicates

I got two Data Frames which I combine and they definitely have duplicates as shown later:

```
total_scrobbles = total_scrobbles.append(new_scrobbles)
```

After that the drop_duplicates Function doesnt do anything. Not a single row is deleted.

```
total_scrobbles.drop_duplicates(inplace = True)
```

But if I save the new DataFrame as a CSV, load it and use the same drop function again it is working:

```
total_scrobbles.to_csv('test.csv', index=False)
total_scrobbles = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
total_scrobbles.drop_duplicates(inplace = True)
```

Now all duplicates are deleted.

I mean, i found a solution. But can anybody tell me why this error occurs?
In my head it doesn't make any sense.
Is there a better solution than save and read_csv for nothing?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you checked if both DataFrames are exactly the same?

Comment: My guess it has something to do the the data format youre using, but it is impossible to tell without the data. Provide ~10 problematic rows for which the problem reproduces!

Comment: Yes, some sample data would be good. You could also experiment with the `subset` argument to the `drop_duplicates()` method, to see which columns are causing the problem.